# sha256sum and hashalot produce different values on Linux

Tags: linux, sha256, checksum, linux-mint

Suddenly I’ve discovered that two various SHA-256 calculators produce different values. Here is the real example — having had downloaded a ‛Neovim’ image, at first I didn’t get what was going on:

```
> cat nvim.appimage | sha256sum
ef9056e05ef6a4c1d0cdb8b21f79261703122c0fd31f23f782158d326fdadbf5  -

> cat nvim.appimage | hashalot -x sha256
ced1af6d51438341a0335cc00e1c2867fb718a537c1173cf210070a6b1cdf40a
```

The correct result is what ‛sha256sum’ gives — it matches the value on the official page. Did I do anything wrong? And how to avoid such unexpected effects in the future?

The operating system is Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon.

Comment: You may want to read the man page for hashalot...

Comment: Oh, thanks! I forgot the name of the proper program, and after typing the wrong name, the shell suggested installing “hashalot” to calculate the sum. I did and read the man page but just only the first lines. If I had looked deeper, I wouldn’t be wondering and didn’t ask the question. The answer has turned out so simple. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user17732522 (https://stackoverflow.com/users/17732522/user17732522)

I forgot the name of the proper program, and after typing the wrong name, the shell suggested installing `hashalot` to calculate the sum. I did and read the man page but just only the first lines. If I had looked deeper, I wouldn’t be wondering and didn’t ask the question. The answer has turned out so simple. Thanks a lot!